# How Can I Change left column in the agenda day of Full calendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

```
        $(document).ready(function () {              
            var events = [];               
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Calendar/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (i, v)
                    {
                        events.push({
                            Id: v.Id,
                            title: v.ShiftName,
                            description: v.EmployeeName,
                            start: moment(v.CreatedDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a'),
                            end: moment(v.CreatedDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a')
                        });
                    })



                    GenerateCalender(events);
                },

            })

        })
```

Here it's the function that renders the calendar

```
function GenerateCalender(events)
            { 
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                    header:
                    {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    buttonText: {
                        today: 'today',
                       // month: 'month',
                        week: 'week',
                        day: 'day'
                    },                                     
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: events.ThemeColour,
                    events: events,                   
                })
            }
```

**I need to change left column of agenda day, Instead of Timing there should be My Employee Name List,
and According to Employee Need to Show events in each row.**

Comment: Could you provide more info? You need to fix the calendar render, isn't it? So I think the issue is inside the function 'GenerateCalendar' . Is it possible to share this function implementation?

Comment: function GenerateCalender(events){ 
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  header:
 {
  left: 'prev,next today',
 center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
     },
     buttonText: {
      today: 'today',
        // month: 'month',
       week: 'week',
             day: 'day'
      },                                     
       eventLimit: true,
     eventColor: events.ThemeColour,
          events: events,                   
            })     }

Comment: My code is working properly ..but i have to change Left column (all-day) in calendar...Instead of all-day column i need EmployeeList ....and according to employee list need to show events in each rows.

Comment: I can see that you're using the library fullcalendar. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with this library. I think you could update your question mentioning it and the render calendar function as well and hopefully someone more familiar with it will help you

Comment: render calendar function I have mentioned above in code,    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>